# Json parse sub-collection in c#

Tags: c#, json

How can I do `JSON` in `C#` like the data below ?

```
{
    "Aliases": [ "teddy", "freddy", "eddy", "Betty" ], 
    "Name":"reacher gilt", 
    "Address":"100 East Way", 
    "Age":74, 
    "Bars": { 
        "items": [ 
            {
                "Sub_Property1":"beep", 
                "Sub_Property2":"boop" 
            },
            {
                "Sub_Property1":"meep",
                "Sub_Property2":"moop"
            },
            {
                "Sub_Property1":"feep",
                "Sub_Property2":"foop"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Actually  my problem is inside the sub-collection. I saw someone did something 
like this

```
person.Bars.Add("items",
        new List<BarClass>(new[]{ 
        new BarClass("beep","boop"),
        new BarClass("meep","moop"),
        new BarClass("feep","foop"),
    }));
```

So, I have to add `new BarClass("beep","boop")`, but I need to do something
like this

```
String [] no1 = {1,2,3}
String [] no2 = {4,5,6}
person.Bars.Add("items",
    new List<BarClass>(new[]{                 
    for ()
        {
           new BarClass(no1[i],no2[i])
        }      
}));
```

How can i do this? Thanks and please help..

Comment: please clearify you question. what are you trying, where did you fail?

Comment: JSON is a language that has it's syntax, please show us what object you want to represent with JSON and as nozzleman said, what have you tried so far

Comment: Are you trying to *"read"* the `JSON` that you already have, or *"create"* a new `JSON` in the given format?

Comment: @FelixAv _"JSON is a language"_ - well no it's a language-independent _data format_.

Comment: @Micky don't be picky ;-) but yeah, you right

Comment: @FelixAv True true. Sorry was passing the time waiting to StarCraft to load ;)

Comment: @Micky & @ FelixAv :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To read the `JSON`**

The best way to read the whole `JSON` is to `Deserialize` it to a native `C#` object. If you do not already have the classes with your, you can create it in Visual Studio as

> - Copy your JSON text
> - Create a new empty class file in VS
> - Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes

Here are the classes

```
public class Person
{
    public string[] Aliases { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Bars Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bars
{
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Sub_Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Sub_Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use some `.NET JSON` library to deserialize. `JSON.Net` aka `Newtonsoft JSON` is a great [library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). You get get it from `NuGet` as well.

Then it's pretty easy to get the `C#` object from the `JSON`

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\person.json");
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonString);
```

If you want to read the sub-collection only, you can rather use [Linq-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) to read the `items` directly, like this

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
List<Item> details = jObject["Bars"]["items"].ToObject<List<Item>>();
```

**To create the JSON**

You first need to create the object, then `Serialize` to `JSON`

```
string[] subProperties1 = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
string[] subProperties2 = new string[] { "4", "5", "6" };

Person person = new Person { Name = "Johny", Age = 7, Address = "Earth", Aliases = new string[] { "Sony", "Monty" } };
person.Bars = new Bars { 
    items = subProperties1.Zip(subProperties2, 
                                (prop1, prop2) => new Item { Sub_Property1 = prop1, Sub_Property2 = prop2 })
                            .ToArray() };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

To create the `items` from your existing `string` arrays, I have used `IEnumerable.Zip` function from `Linq`. You can read about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx).

This is the created `JSON` data

```
{
  "Aliases": [ "Sony", "Monty" ],
  "Name": "Johny",
  "Address": "Earth",
  "Age": 7,
  "Bars": {
    "items": [
      {
        "Sub_Property1": "1",
        "Sub_Property2": "4"
      },
      {
        "Sub_Property1": "2",
        "Sub_Property2": "5"
      },
      {
        "Sub_Property1": "3",
        "Sub_Property2": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Arghya please me another issue please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044127/json-pare-sub-collection

Answer (score 0):

You should create some classes

```
public class Person
{
 public string Name {get;set;}    
 public string Address{get;set;}
 public int Age {get;set;}
 public Header {get;set;}
}    

public class Header
{
 public Detail[] Details {get;set;}
}

public class Detail
{
 public string Sub1 {get;set;}
 public string Sub2 {get;set;}
}
```

Create instance from Person class and initialize to instance after than

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer =new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result=serializer.Serialize(instanceOfPerson);
```

"result" is json data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean you want to create JSON string, you need to create those classes and use something like Newtonsoft JSON.net:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Sub_Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Sub_Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Bars
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public List<string> Aliases { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Bars Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Please read the documentation here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm