# How to create Json from header and detail class

Tags: c#, json, linq

This is json class that I was design and contain header and also detail,  and I'm using Visual studio 2015

```
public class SubDetail
    {
        public string Sub1 { get; set; }
        public string Sub2 { get; set; }
        public string Sub3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string No { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<SubDetail> SubDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

and How to write c# code by using linq and get json out put like below

```
[
 {  
    "No":"1",
    "Age":7,
    "SubDetail":            
    [
    {   
      "Sub1":"1",
    "Sub2":"2",
    "Sub3":"3"
    },
    {
    "Sub1":"4",
    "Sub2":"5",
    "Sub3":"6"
    },
              { 
    "Sub1":"7",
    "Sub2":"8",
    "Sub3":"9"
    }               
              ]         
   }    
]
```

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Comment: `var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(yourObject);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SubDetail
{
    public string Sub1 { get; set; }
    public string Sub2 { get; set; }
    public string Sub3 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string No { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<SubDetail> SubDetail { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RootObject obj = new RootObject();
        obj.No = "1";
        obj.Age = 7;

        int lenght = 3;
        int counter = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<lenght; i++)
        {
            SubDetail detail = new SubDetail();
            detail.Sub1 = (counter + 1).ToString();
            detail.Sub2 = (counter + 1).ToString();
            detail.Sub3 = (counter + 1).ToString();

            if (obj.SubDetail == null)
                obj.SubDetail = new List<SubDetail>();

            obj.SubDetail.Add(detail);
        }

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);

    }
}
```

Here is full example for your case. Also you need to add Newtonsoft.Json dll to your project you can do it with this line in the Package Manager Console.

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 7.0.1
```

Comment: I suppose some kind of a rage but whatever :)

Answer (score 3):

There are any number of libraries for serializing an object graph into JSON format. The most popular and easy to use is [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which will allow you to generate your JSON easily with one line:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myRootObject);
```

This has nothing to do with LINQ, mostly because there's no need for you to explore your SubDetail collection and generate the JSON manually. Use a standard, accepted, *tested* solution.

Comment: Please give me the sample code in c# that how to use ? I'm very quite new. Thanks

Comment: Seriously? I have *given* you the one line of sample code.